# How should I think of $dim_x(X)=\inf\{dim(U)|$ U open neighborhood of $x\}$ where $dim(U)$ is defined by longest chain of irreducible closed sets.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

This is related to Iitaka's Algebraic Geometry a.Definition on pg 22 of Sec 1.9.

$X$ is a non-empty topological space. Dimension of $X$ is supremum of all non-negative integers $l$ for which $F_i$ are closed irreducibles s.t. $\emptyset\neq F_0\subset F_1\subset\dots\subset F_l\subset X$ where we require inclusion is proper here.

Set $x\in X$. Define dimension of $X$ at $x$ by $dim_x(X)=\inf\{dim (U)\vert U$ is an open neighborhood of $x\}$

$\textbf{Q:}$ How should I think of $dim_x(X)$? What is a good example? It looks like that $dim_x(X)$ only sees the smallest irreducible component of $X$ containing $x$. Note that $dim_x(X)$ is defined by taking infinimum rather than supremum. What do I expect so?

Comment: Smallest? Are you sure?

Comment: In any case imagine the union of a line and a plan transverse to it, and let $x$ be the intersection point, what would you want the dimension at $x$ to be? This definitions gives you 2, which seems fairly reasonnable.

Comment: @Ahr Yes. My bad. I was thinking as $dim(U)$ is always $2$ in your case but when I wrote, I wrote something completely opposite. I was thinking something like $2$ dimension variety union a curve with tangency. I guess this should coincide with normal complex geometric sense. The only thing makes me uncomfortable is that you are taking over $\inf$ rather than $\sup$. What is the reason to expect taking $\inf$ here?

Comment: Well if you take a supremum, then you can add up any big open subset that does not contain $x$ and that will mess things up. Take $X$ to be as before, the union of a line and a plane that intersect at a point $x$ and take $Y$ to be the disjoint union of $X$ and a variety of dimension $n$, then if you take a sup, the dimension at $x$ would be n, we certainly don't want that.

Comment: @Ahr Ah. I see. So roughly speaking $\inf$ is to throw away irrelevant information as like disjoint union part.

Comment: Exactly. And to reply to your previous comment, if you take a surface and a line tangent to it, the the dimension at a tangency point is still 2, which is what we want, again.